# Android: FileProvider.getUriForFile "Failed to find configured root"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to implement a camera activity where the user takes a picture and saves it to the phone.

**Error:**
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/no.test.group_project/files/Pictures/JPEG_20200423_114453_750680396837474735.jpg`

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="no.test.group_project.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

**file_paths.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/no.test/group_project/files/Pictures/" />
</paths>
```

**Java**

```
    public void openCamera(View view) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "no.test.group_project.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Utils.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

I am getting above error when I try to get the Uri from

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
    "no.test.group_project.fileprovider",
    photoFile
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `path="Android/data/asmund.thomas.group_project/files/Pictures/"` with `path="."`.